# Загрузка файла с именем в mysql при помощи php

Tags: php, mysql

задача в том, чтоб передать в таблицу имя pdf файла, но при попытке отправить текстовое значение в поле namep поле таблицы не заполняется
структура mysql след.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Суть в том, что надо заполнять поле namep для того, чтобы находить необходимый pdf файл в базе данных

```
<form action="newtest.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p> down pdf </p>
<input type="file" name="pdf_upload"><input type="submit" name="upload" value="zagruzka">
<input type="text" name="name_pdf">
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
        if(!empty($_FILES['pdf_upload']['tmp_name'])) $pdf = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['pdf_upload']['tmp_name']));
        $connection->query("INSERT INTO dapdf (pdf) VALUES ('$pdf')");
        }
    if(isset($_POST['text'])){
        if(!empty($_FILES['name_pdf'])) $pdfname = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['name_pdf']));
        $connection->query("INSERT INTO dapdf (namep) VALUES ('$pdfname')");
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: А это что `$_FILES['name_pdf']`?

Comment: @u_mulder, переменная загружаемся по http

Comment: Вы там разберитесь чем `$_FILES` отличает от `$_POST`.

Comment: @u_mulder, подскажите пожалуйста как заполнить namep,чтобы при загрузке pdf и namep рядом заполнялось, просто надо иметь строку с именем пдэфки, буду благодарен

Comment: `print_r($_FILES); print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Не нужно хранить в базе сам файл. Файл загружайте на сервер.
В базу сохраняйте его имя, и путь до него.

Если хотите переименовывать файл, то это надо делать ДО его загрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убрать из кода использование функции `file_get_contents` — она получает содержимое файла, а вам нужно только его название.